# Simular una especie de FOR EACH en Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Actualmente estoy realizando una consulta que muestra el total de informes de un tipo especifico enviados (enviado=1) por cada usuario. La consulta actual que tengo funciona y es:

```
SELECT username,

SUM(inf_name='INF_01') AS INF_01, 
SUM(inf_name='INF_02') AS INF_02, 
SUM(inf_name='INF_03') AS INF_03, 
SUM(inf_name='INF_04') AS INF_04, 
SUM(inf_name='INF_05') AS INF_05

FROM  `informes` 
WHERE enviado=1
GROUP BY username
```

Mi pregunta es si existe una forma para realizar esos SUM()... de forma que cuando se ingrese un nuevo tipo de informe (ej INF_06) no se deba editar la consulta, simular una especie de FOR EACH que me permite tener la cantidad total por cada tipo de informe y mostrarlo como una nueva columna para la consulta.

Saludos.

Comment: Siempre seran 6 informes o es dinamico?

Comment: La cantidad es dinámica, incluso eliminar alguno de los informes.

Comment: Definitivamente se puede hacer en MySQL, lo único que de preferencia tendría que ser un procedimiento almacenado, hace unos días yo utilice algo similar con FOREACH, y el siguiente link me ayudo bastante. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775521/mysql-foreach-alternative-for-procedure Espero te sirva de algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma posible es construir una consulta dinámica, veamos esta prueba de concepto:

```
create table if not exists informes(
    username varchar(255),
    inf_name varchar(255)

);

insert into informes(username, inf_name) values ( 'juan',  'INF_01');
insert into informes(username, inf_name) values ( 'pedro', 'INF_01');
insert into informes(username, inf_name) values ( 'juan',  'INF_02');
insert into informes(username, inf_name) values ( 'luis',  'INF_03');

SET @sumas = "";
select  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("sum(inf_name='", inf_name, "') AS ", inf_name) SEPARATOR ', ')
        INTO @sumas
        from ( select inf_name
                      from informes
                      group by inf_name
              ) G;

SET @query = CONCAT("select username, ", @sumas, " FROM informes GROUP BY username; ");
select @query;
```

Si revisamos la variable `@query` vemos como nos queda la consulta:

```
select username, sum(inf_name='INF_01') AS INF_01, sum(inf_name='INF_02') AS INF_02, sum(inf_name='INF_03') AS INF_03 FROM informes GROUP BY username;
```

Le podemos agregar saltos de línea para que se vea mejor, pero más allá de eso, es básicamente lo que buscabas, pero construido dinámicamente,  lo único que nos resta es ejecutarla, así:

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query; 
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Y obtendremos la salida buscada:

```
username INF_01 INF_02 INF_03
======== ====== ====== ======
juan     1      1      0
luis     0      0      1
pedro    1      0      0
```

Por supuesto toda consulta dinámica tiene límites:

- Tamaño de la variable `@query`
- Cantidad de columnas que puede devolver una consulta

No conozco puntualmente los de MySql, te sugiero que los investigues.